# ConTeXt: horizontal alignment with `t-vim` module

Tags: context, context-lmtx

Is it possible to horizontally align `t-vim` module code blocks?

I tried with `\{start|stop}alignement` like so

```tex
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping[python][syntax=python]

\starttext
    \startalignment[middle]
        \startpython
            print("Hello, world!")
        \stoppython
    \stopalignment
\stoptext
```

and with `align=middle`

```tex
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping[python][syntax=python, align=middle]

\starttext
    \startpython
        print("Hello, world!")
    \stoppython
\stoptext
```

Both results were like this output:

[image]

I have also checked [the documentation](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/vim-README.md) and [the source code](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/t-vim.tex) but I could not find anything else. Did I miss something?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve? There is an explicit `\raggedright` in the code, which overrides the value of `align=middle`. If that was not there, all lines will be middle aligned (so we will lose indentation etc.). What do you want to achieve? Center a code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret middle alignment for code blocks:

1. Middle align each line
2. Middle align the complete code block

The first doesn't make sense for codes. For that reason, the code in `t-vim` includes an explicit `\raggedright`, so that outer alignment setting do not effect how the code is typeset.

If you want to middle align the complete code block, then you can simply wrap it in a `\framed` and center that framed.

```
\usemodule[vim]

\defineframed[PYTHONframed][align=normal,frame=off]

\definevimtyping
  [python]
  [
    syntax=python,
    before={\blank\midaligned\bgroup\PYTHONframed\bgroup},
    after={\egroup\egroup\blank},
  ]

\starttext
\starttext
    \startpython
        for x = 1 upto 10:
            print("Hello, world!")
    \stoppython
\stoptext
\stoptext
```

Note that above code has a drawback that the code can no longer break across pages. It is possible to have a wrapped that will break across pages, but it is more complicated. I don't quite understand a usecase where that will be needed, but if there is one, I can show how to do that.

Comment: I am quite confident that I will not have the need to break code across pages for now. However if you have time I would still like to learn how to do it, in case my needs change over time.

Comment: I'll leave a comment on how to implement it. The main idea is that you typeset the code inside a box, measure the width of the box, and unbox the content in a paragraph where the leftskip equal width/2 (e.g., using the narrower environment).